# cross compile opencv for mips processor

Tags: opencv, mips, cross-compiling, axis

I am trying to create an application for an embed axis camera that it has MIPS processor. I am using opencv with my project. Right now, after running create-package.sh mipsisa32r2el,I received errors that it was skipping incompatible libraries and it couldn't find the library. I think I should cross-compile opencv for MIPS processor but I don't know how can I do that. I already checked the opencv documentation  but I didn't find cross compiling for MIPS processor.

Comment: Are you using a mips toolchain (gcc,etc...) to compile it? Also, the missing libraries need to be present.

Comment: In the create-package.sh it uses mipsisa32r2el-axis-linux-gnu-gcc to compile the project. It misses all the libraries of opencv.

Comment: Oh ok, i guess you are building it for an Axis camera, it will be a loooong process :)

Answer (score 1):

From your comments it looks like your compilation script is already using a gcc that cross-compiles for MIPS (`mipsisa32r2el-axis-linux-gnu-gcc` looks like it comes from a toolchain for Axis cameras), **if you don't have that gcc** (maybe the script refers to it but you don't have it) , you need to build a mips32el toolchain with something like [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) or [Crosstool-NG](http://crosstool-ng.org/), it's not too hard (and the missing libraries could already be selectable in the toolchain building script).

You mainly have two problems here, related to the fact that you don't have all the required dependencies/libraries:

1. Some libraries are *incompatible*: The toolchain's gcc couldn't find a required library and it's trying to use the one present on the host os
2. Some libraries are completely *missing*: The toolchain's gcc couldn't find that library anywhere

To solve these issues, every time the compilation script does not find a library, build it, and place the generated .so in one of the directories of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Do this for every missing/incompatible library.
It will be a long process.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It definitely help

Answer (score 1):

I found an easier way to compile opencv code for mips processor by changing the arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmak to use MIPS compiler
here is the changed cmake:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR mips)

set(GCC_COMPILER_VERSION "4.6" CACHE STRING "GCC Compiler version")

set(FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX "")
if (NOT SOFTFP)
  set(FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX "hf")
endif()

#find_program(CMAKE_C_COMPILER NAMES mipsisa32r2el-axis-linux-        gnu${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX}-gcc${GCC_COMPILER_VERSION})
#find_program(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER NAMES mipsisa32r2el-axis-linux-    gnu${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX}-g++${GCC_COMPILER_VERSION})
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/local/mipsisa32r2el/r12/bin/mipsisa32r2el-axis-  linux-gnu-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/local/mipsisa32r2el/r12/bin/mipsisa32r2el-axis-linux-gnu-g++) 
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS           ""                    CACHE STRING "c++ flags")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS             ""                    CACHE STRING "c flags")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS ""                    CACHE STRING "shared  linker flags")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS ""                    CACHE STRING "module linker flags")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS    "-Wl,-z,nocopyreloc"  CACHE STRING "executable linker flags")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -  fsigned-char ")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS   "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}  -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char ")

set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now ${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS    "-Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")

if(USE_NEON)
  message(WARNING "You use obsolete variable USE_NEON to enable NEON    instruction set. Use -DENABLE_NEON=ON instead." )
  set(ENABLE_NEON TRUE)
elseif(USE_VFPV3)
  message(WARNING "You use obsolete variable USE_VFPV3 to enable VFPV3 instruction set. Use -DENABLE_VFPV3=ON instead." )
  set(ENABLE_VFPV3 TRUE)
endif()

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH} ${MIPS_LINUX_SYSROOT})

if(EXISTS ${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR})
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}     ${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR})
endif()

set( CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH TRUE CACHE BOOL "If set, runtime paths are not added  when using shared libraries." )
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM ONLY)

# macro to find programs on the host OS
macro( find_host_program )
 set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER )
 set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY NEVER )
 set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE NEVER )
 if( CMAKE_HOST_WIN32 )
  SET( WIN32 1 )
  SET( UNIX )
 elseif( CMAKE_HOST_APPLE )
  SET( APPLE 1 )
  SET( UNIX )
 endif()
 find_program( ${ARGN} )
 SET( WIN32 )
 SET( APPLE )
 SET( UNIX 1 )
 set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM ONLY )
 set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY )
 set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY )
endmacro()

# macro to find packages on the host OS
macro( find_host_package )
 set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER )
 set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY NEVER )
 set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE NEVER )
 if( CMAKE_HOST_WIN32 )
  SET( WIN32 1 )
  SET( UNIX )
 elseif( CMAKE_HOST_APPLE )
  SET( APPLE 1 )
  SET( UNIX )
 endif()
 find_package( ${ARGN} )
SET( WIN32 )
SET( APPLE )
 SET( UNIX 1 )
 set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM ONLY )
 set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY )
 set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY )
endmacro()
```

by usin this cmake I made static libraries of opencv